# Avoid repeating method calls in TypeScript array construction

Tags: typescript, enums

I've got a TypeScript enum with hundreds of values like

```
export enum ObjectTypes {
    OBJ_TYPE_1 = 1,
    OBJ_TYPE_2 = 2,
    OBJ_TYPE_3 = 3,
    OBJ_TYPE_4 = 4,
    OBJ_TYPE_5 = 5,
    OBJ_TYPE_5 = 6,
    ...
    OBJ_TYPE_500 = 500,
}
```

The several places in the application construct arrays like

```
private static ALLOWED_OBJ_TYPES: string[] = [
    ObjectTypes.OBJ_TYPE_1.toString(),
    ObjectTypes.OBJ_TYPE_3.toString(),
    ObjectTypes.OBJ_TYPE_6.toString(),
...
];
```

Is there any shorter more elegant way to declare these arrays avoiding the repetition of `ObjectTypes.` and `.toString()`?

Note that the set of enum value for each array varies arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will avoid a couple of keystrokes, and is still type safe, not sure if it is necessarily more elegant, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder :)

```
export enum ObjectTypes {
    OBJ_TYPE_1 = 1,
    OBJ_TYPE_2 = 2,
    OBJ_TYPE_3 = 3,
    OBJ_TYPE_4 = 4,
    OBJ_TYPE_5 = 5,
    OBJ_TYPE_5 = 6,
    OBJ_TYPE_500 = 500,
}

function createEnumArray<T>(e: T, ...keys: Array<keyof T>) {
    return keys.map(k => e[k].toString())
}

let ALLOWED_OBJ_TYPES: string[] = createEnumArray(ObjectTypes, 
    "OBJ_TYPE_1",
    "OBJ_TYPE_3",
    "OBJ_TYPE_6",
);
```